# MySQL - GROUP results BY a single column alongside ORDER BY and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, limit

I want to select a list of tasks from my database. The tasks have a `category_id`. I want to get a singlur task per `category_id`. So if I, for example, had 10 `task`s that are linked to like 6 `categories` that would result in **6** results. The 6 results I want are determined by their id, the lowest `id` among the `GROUP BY` is the correct record for that `GROUP`. Also the maximum result set can be no larger than 20 ('LIMIT').

```
SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE `datetime`<NOW()  `task_status_id`=1 GROUP BY `category_id` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 20
```

What is wrong with the above query, I got no clue, I'm also at a loss getting any google results for this.

ADDED LATER

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa39cf

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);


CREATE TABLE `task` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `task_status_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '1',
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `task` (`id`, `category_id`, `task_status_id`, `datetime`) VALUES
(3, 2, 1, '2018-07-24 11:20:26'),
(4, 2, 1, '2018-07-24 11:20:26'),
(5, 3, 1, '2018-07-24 11:21:35'),
(6, 3, 1, '2018-07-24 11:21:35');
```

Comment: @Strawberry added the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try first finding the smallest id for each category and then joining it with the task table to get the remaining details.

```
SELECT t.* FROM task t 
JOIN (SELECT category_id, min(id) id from task group by category_id) tc 
    ON (t.id = tc.id)
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.